# How do I extract the body of the HTML from a fetch?

Tags: javascript, html, html-parsing, fetch

How can I extract the body from this fetch statement?  I can successfully fetch the url, but I'm looking for some specific HTML elements in the result set.  When I run the script in JSFiddle is provides results, but it stops because the html is improperly formed and cannot be parsed by the DomParser.  I would like the results to be returned as a string so I can use regex to parse the result set.

Note: the government site has a broken API since last June.  I'm trying alternate ways to get to the data that used to be provided via API.

I have been able to successfully parse this using Google Apps Script, but I want this to work in a stand alone, html form using JavaScript

```
 fetch('https://safer.fmcsa.dot.gov/query.asp? searchtype=ANY&query_type=queryCarrierSnapshot&query_param=MC_MX&query_string=146892', {
      mode: 'no-cors' // 'cors' by default
     })
     .then(function(response) {
     // When the page is loaded convert it to text
     return response.text()
     })
    .then(function(htmlString) {
     // Initialize the DOM parser
     var parser = new DOMParser();
     // Parse the text
     var doc = parser.parseFromString(htmlString, "text/xml");      
     // You can now even select part of that html as you would in the regular DOM 
     // Example:
     // var docArticle = doc.querySelector('article').innerHTML;
     console.log(doc);
     })
     .catch(function(err) {  
     console.log('Failed to fetch page: ', err);  
     });
```

This is the JSFiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/6b9s1Lwz/
It returns a parse error.

This is my working Apps Script Code:  It works perfectly, trying to get this to work in javascript is my challenge.

```
function getSaferData() {
  var saferUrl = 'https://safer.fmcsa.dot.gov/query.asp?searchtype=ANY&query_type=queryCarrierSnapshot&query_param=MC_MX&query_string=';
  var MCNum =146892;
  var fetchUrl =saferUrl+MCNum;
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(fetchUrl);
  var result = response.getContentText().match(/<B>(.*?)<\/B>/g);
  var carrierName = result[1].replace(/<\/?B>/g,'')
  Logger.log(result + " " +  result.length);
  console.log(carrierName);
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange(1,1).setValue(carrierName);  
}
```

Comment: use `var doc = parser.parseFromString(htmlString, "text/html");` because you say you are getting **HTML** so why parse **XML** ?

Comment: Also ARE you parseing anything? Does the fetch return anything? I get empty string when I do `console.log(response.text())`

Comment: If you fix the type, [it works](https://jsfiddle.net/tjcrowder/6kj0u247/). HTML is `text/html`, not `text/xml`. Very, very, very, very little HTML in the wild is valid XML. (Even when people think they're writing XHTML, they're often wrong.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder The document you are console.logging is empty - likely CORS issue

Comment: @mplungjan - But the parse error is fixed. ;-)

Comment: Yeah. I would personally user a document fragment

Comment: I orginally had text/html but it did not work, so I switched to text/xml.  When I update the JSFiddle it shows me even less information.  Just the <html> and <body> tags.  Yes, the parser error is gone, but the goal is to get the data.  I added the mode: 'no-cors' so that I could fetch the URL.

Comment: I updated my post with the working Apps Script Code.  Basically I need to parse some of the <B> elements and I really just want to fetch the data as a string and regex it.

Comment: @JoyHanawa You will not be able to on the client. You will need to write a proxy on the server that will fetch the file. For security reasons you do not have programmatical access to the file in the browser since the site has not implemented CORS (which you even turned off)

Comment: @mplungjan - How is I can access it no problem from a google app script?

Comment: @mplungjan  Here is the link... https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Wa6yWYF6gBWvKd9Jlwiz_Obkc4rsRx9tWG_iPhUazME/edit?usp=sharing